How can I share a common script between background and content scripts in Chrome Extension?
So I have a settings object, which is configured by the options page in my extension. This stores the data in chrome.storage.local.
const DEFAULT_SETTINGS  = {
    css: {
        test:true
       }
    }

let settings = { ...DEFAULT_SETTINGS };

// Function to load settings from chrome.storage.local
function loadSettings(callback) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('settings', (result) => {
        if (result.settings) {
            settings = JSON.parse(result.settings);
        }
        if (callback) callback(settings);
    });
}

// Function to save settings to chrome.storage.local
function saveSettings(callback) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ settings: JSON.stringify(settings) }, () => {
        console.log('Settings saved:', settings);
        if (callback) callback();
    });
}

 // Expose the functions and settings object
export { settings, loadSettings, saveSettings }; 

The options page has the following line so that it can use settings:
import { settings, loadSettings, saveSettings } from './settings.js';

This all works perfectly.
My background script loads settings and also has a reference to the settings.js file and makes them available to content scripts via messaging.
 import { settings, loadSettings, saveSettings } from './settings.js';

/ Listen for messages from content scripts
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    switch (request.action) {
    case "getSettings":
            sendResponse({ settings });
            break;
        case "saveSettings":
            settings = request.settings;
            saveSettings(() => sendResponse({ status: "success" }));
            break;
    }
    return true;
});

This all works fine.
The problem came when I tried to use settings.js in my content script
Adding the reference in my manifest:
"content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://localhost:8000/*", "https://www.amazon.co.uk/vine/vine-items*"],
        "js": ["settings.js", "manicviner.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
      }
    ],

Gave an error when I reloaded the extension as it didn't like the export in settings.js.
Removing the reference does allow me to pass settings into the content script via messaging.
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "getSettings" }, (response) => {
    const mysettings = response.settings;
    console.log(mysettings); // Now you can use the settings

});

However, it is just the JSON that comes back - I cannot use the settings object itself because the content script has no knowledge of the object structure.
Apparently, ES6 modules cannot be used in content scripts - which is the root of the issue here. Sp how can I structure my code so that when I use settings in my content script, I have access to the object model as defined in settings.js, e.g. settings.css.test.

From the point of view of your code, everything seems to look right. And yes, you can use ES6 modules in content-scripts files, if you use a builder, such as vite. If not, you can try to find answers and solutions to this topic here.
I will in turn give a minimally working example using the vite builder. The structure of my project now looks like this:

package.json:
{
  "name": "untitled1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@crxjs/vite-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.19",
    "vite": "^4.4.11"
  }
}

vite.config.mjs:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import manifest from './src/manifest.js';

const r = (...args) => resolve(__dirname, ...args)

export default defineConfig(( ) => {
  return {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '~/': `${r('src')}/`,
        '@': `${r('src')}/`,
      },
    },
    build: {
      emptyOutDir: true,
      outDir: 'build',
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          chunkFileNames: 'assets/chunk-[hash].js',
        },
      },
    },
    server: {
      host: true,
      port: 8000,
      watch: {
        usePolling: true
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      crx({ manifest }),
    ],
  }
});

Instead of manifest.json, manifest.js is used, which will be built at startup.
manifest.js
import { defineManifest } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin';

export default defineManifest({
  name: "Test extension",
  version: "1.0",
  manifest_version: 3,
  background: {
    service_worker: "src/service-worker.js",
    type: "module"
  },
  content_scripts: [
    {
      matches: ["<all_urls>"],
      js: ["src/content-script.js"],
    }
  ],
});

settings.js
export const DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
  css: {
    test: true,
  },
};

content-script.js
import { DEFAULT_SETTINGS } from "./settings.js";

console.log('CONTENT WAS LOADED', 'SETTINGS => ', DEFAULT_SETTINGS);

service-worker.js
import { DEFAULT_SETTINGS } from "./settings.js";

console.log('BACKGROUND WAS LOADED', 'SETTINGS => ', DEFAULT_SETTINGS);

Besides imports, the plus side of this approach is that the build will change dynamically, and you don't need to reload it in chrome to synchronize. Run the npm run dev command in the console, the build folder will appear in the project folder, load it into chrome and continue development.
Now if I open the console in chrome on any site, I see this:

And this inside server-worker console :

And check if you forgot to specify .js at the end when importing the file inside content script, it's unlikely, but possible. For example, you use:
import { someObject } from './file';
// You should have used
import { someObject } from './file.js';


This doesn't work for me.
Whether I include settings.js in the manifest or not, the line in my content script that imports settings.js triggers the error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I have substantially revised the answer. I forgot that we are using the vite builder. Added a minimal working example of how to set this up. I also added a link to a similar problem where there are examples without using the import builder.
